# Не удается установить эмулятор для Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, эмулятор

у меня в студии выдает ошибку при установки Intel HAXM, решила сама через интернет установить этот эмулятор, в итоге выдает ошибку. У меня процессор AMD, виртуализация включена, что делать? помогите пожалуйста(([image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насколько я помню, на AMD(старых процессорах по типу Phenom) нужно использовать не ARM, а x86 архитектуру виртуальной машины

Comment: так а как скачать эмулятор то?

Comment: Насколько я помню, там есть 3 вкладки архитектур эмуляторов(Установленные, ARM, x86), Так вот, вам нужна 3 вкладка, там берете тот, что вам нужен

Comment: Вы же говорите про андроид студию?

Comment: да, зайдите в настройки Виртуальных машин, а дальше как в комментарии выше

Comment: Извините, а где в студии настройки Виртуальных машин? я с этой средой работаю не долго, поэтому немного не понимаю о чем ВЫ

Comment: Настройки -> AVD менеджер(или что-то похожее). Там выберете нужный телефон и потом идете во вкладку x86 images

Answer (score 0):

Дополню комментарии под вашим вопросом.

`Menu -> Tools -> AVD Manager`

Откроется окно **Your Virtual Devices**

Нажмите на пиктограмму редактирования(карандашик) на интересующем эмуляторе

Откроется окно **Android Virtual Device**

Нажмите на кнопку изменения образа системы и перейдите на вкладку x86 Images

Скачайте и выберите `x86` образ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: все равно выдает ошибку и говори что не установлен HAXM, а он не устанавливается. Возможно ли установить другой эмулятор? или как то решить эту проблему?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/429610/

Comment: как и написано я запустила командную строку, написала команду и вот результат: Расширения режима мониторинга виртуальной машины: Да
                  Виртуализация включена во встроенном ПО: Да
                   Преобразование адресов второго уровня: Да
                   Доступно предотвращение выполнения данных: Да
Должно все работать вроде, а haxm не устанавливается

Comment: Установите  Genimotion ‍♂️

Comment: На сколько я знаю, он платный, но ладно, при запуске приложения в студии, он автоматически откроется?

Comment: Есть лицензия для личного использования, она бесплатная. Да, в студии будет виден как полноценный девайс

Comment: спасибочки, сейчас попробую